# Can't create blank Android Xamarin app in VS 2017.the error shows

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Can't create blank Android Xamarin app in VS 2017
The error shows invalid pointer (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004003 (E_POINTER))

Comment: Have you tried running a repair of the Visual Studio install?

Comment: How about using Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio 2017 did you use? This issue occurs for the previous version and has been fixed in version 15.9.4. Try to update the VS to 15.9.4 or higher. Check the link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#-visual-studio-2017-version-1594